# Who wins in a game of card draw

Tags: probability, card-games

Consider Ace to be \$1, 2 is \$2, all the way up to King being \$13.

I (Player A) shuffle a standard 52 card deck and draw 3 cards, then my friend (Player B) draws 3 cards.

The person with the highest dollar value wins that amount, and in addition, the loser pays their total sum to the other player.

Eg Player A drew \$20 (two sixes and an eight), Player B drew \$36 (Three queens), then Player B wins \$36, and Player A loses \$20 he must give to player B, so player B made \$56 profit.

i) What is the expected winnings for player A and B after 1 game?

I don't know how to approach this question, it feels like an overwhelming number of possibilities on a case by case basis. Is there a quicker way to calculate?

Comment: It looks like a fair zero-sum game, which would make each player's expectation simple.  Or I may have misunderstood the question